# selects dinámicos dependientes php, ajax y postgres

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola estoy haciendo unos selects dinámicos dependientes, el caso es que el segundo select solamente me devuelve un resultado que además es el último, y si ejecuto la consulta en pgadmin me devuelve 10 resultados.
Consulta para el primer select:

```
$query = "SELECT distinct 
    vl_spe.id_finca, vl_spe.name, vl_obs.id_code from vl_spe
LEFT JOIN 
    vl_obs on vl_spe.id_code = vl_obs.id_code 
WHERE 
    vl_obs.id_observation_font = 3 
ORDER BY name";

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
```

En el index pongo los Selects

```
<div class="campaSelect">
<select id="cbx_esp" name="cbx_esp" class="select-selected">
    <option value="0">Seleccionar finca...</option>
    <?php
        while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['id_code']; ?>"><?php echo $line['name']; ?></option>   
    <?php }?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="campaSelect">
    <select id="cbx_camp" name="cbx_camp" class="select-selected"></select>
</div>
```

La función que cambia el select

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbx_esp").on('change', function () {
        $("#cbx_esp option:selected").each(function () {
            var id_code = $(this).val();
            $.post("funcionesPHP/getCampa.php", { id_code: id_code }, function(data) {
                $("#cbx_camp").html(data);
            });         
        });
   });
});
```

Y el php al que llama la función. getCampa.php

```
require("db_config.php");
$conexion = "host=$db_host port=$db_port dbname=$db_name user=$db_user password=$db_pass";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conexion);

$id_code = $_POST['id_code'];

$query = "SELECT distinct id_code, camp from vl_obs where id_code = '$id_code' order by camp";

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

$html = "<option value='0'>Seleccione campaña...</option>";

    while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
        $html = "<option value='".$line['id_code']."'>".$line['camp']."</option>";
    }

echo $html;
```

Y el resultado es el comentado, para un nombre que tengo localizado debería de mostrar 10 valores del campo  "camp", pero me muestra 1 único valor y que además es el último. Dónde tengo el error?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás sobrescribiendo la variable `$html` en cada iteración del ciclo. Deberías concatenar  `$html .= 'Contenido adicional';`

Comment: uff, efectivamente! Muchísimas gracias @Triby